# Minute of the respond time (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck with a minute function.  At first i used days_between ( "Created Time", "Locked Time") to check on the responded time in day but know i wish to change to Minutes instead of Days.

Comment: and your code is where? What have you got, what have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming locked time is the later time, you would use:

```
timestampdiff(minute, created_time, locked_time)
```

to get the difference in minutes.